# applying step function when reassigning pandas row

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas tables, `d` and `num_original_introns`. They are both indexed with the same non-numeric index. I want to apply a step function to transform `d` based on values in `d` and `num_original_introns`, like so:

```
d["HasOriginalIntrons"] = d["HasOriginalIntrons"] >= 0.5 * num_original_introns["NumberIntrons"] - 0.5 if num_original_introns["NumberIntrons"] != 0 else False
```

But this gives the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know that this is invalid, and it is not possible to apply a pair of conditionals like this, but I can't seem to find an alternative from googling. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use numpy `logical_and`, `logical_or`, etc. which will create a truth-value array.

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple logical conditions, each one needs to be enclosed in parentheses with an ampersand in-between. For example:

```
d["HasOriginalIntrons"] = (num_original_introns["NumberIntrons"] != 0) & \ 
                          (
                           d["HasOriginalIntrons"] >= 
                             (0.5 * num_original_introns["NumberIntrons"] - 0.5)
                          )
```